# Get Azure KeyVault Secrets from the KeyVault to an App Service using ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

In the Microsoft KeyVault resource I have a secret:

```
        {
          "type": "secrets",
          "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
          "name": "mongodb",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('vault').name)]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "attributes": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "value": "[listConnectionStrings(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', parameters('cosmosAccountName')), '2019-12-12').connectionStrings[0].connectionString]"
          }
        }
```

I want to extract this value and store it in a key-value pair in an App Service.

```
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "COSMOS_CONNECTION_STRING",
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        }
```

They are in the same resource group.

How do I get the value out of the keyvault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to give the `App Service` permission to read the keys from the `KeyVault`, which is done by creating an `Access Policy`.

This is done by:

```
 {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "name": "[concat( variables('vault').name, '/replace')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('vault').name)]",
      ],
      "properties": {
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('AppService').name), '2016-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "Get",
                "List"
              ],
              "certificates": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Then you can access the secret key by:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)
```

Where `myvault` is the name of your vault and
`mysecret` is the name of your secret key

This will create a `KeyVault Reference`.